# How to achive this sql query result in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a error index containing all the errors logged by the php application. Now I want a DSL query whitch returns the distinct errors by message and also the count.

Similar to mysql query:

`SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS total FROM` errors`GROUP BY`message`;`

Mapping for my index:

```
"mappings": {
  "errors": {
    "properties": {
      "message": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "trace": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "file": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Expected result:

> Message | File | Count
>
> Undefined variable $param at line 20 in index.php | project/index.php |  10
>
> Undefined variable $opt at line 15 in helper.php | project/helper.php | 4
>
> ..........

I am using elastic search 5.6. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm expecting your query is this => `SELECT message, COUNT(*) AS total FROM errors GROUP BY message`. I think you are looking for this -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/_executing_aggregations.html#_executing_aggregations

Comment: @Kaushik I know the solution for group by message only and get the count. it is simple group by message. I want the * data also in the select. thats it. thanks. similar to mysql ( select *,count() from ... group by message )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[top hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation could get you there, I think.

```
GET errors/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "error-counts": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "message"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "messages": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 100
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will create buckets for each message, with a total count in each bucket, and with a list of 100 records within each bucket.